# unable to download Google Eclipse plugin 3.6

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm following the instruction indicated in http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.6.html about installing Google plugin in eclipse 3.6.

But every time, i paste the link for Google eclipse plugin 3.6, eclipse prompts an error message saying the specified link could not be found.

Can someone help me 'bout this dilemma. any form of help will be much appreciated. thank you. :|

Answer (score 1):

I found that the Eclipse software repository was missing, even in my brand new installation of Eclipse Helios--I would think it should be present from the beginning, but I guess they forgot.

Add this URL using the *Help > Install New Software* command (the same command you used to add the Google Eclipse Plugin):

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/

and then once again [add the Google Eclipse Plugin](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html#Installing_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [suggestions from the FAQ](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#installfromzip)?

> First, verify that your update site URL is correct for the version of Eclipse that you're using:
>   Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

```
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6
```

> If you're sure that you typed the correct version, you may be behind a firewall that prevents Eclipse from reaching the update site (this is the case in some corporate environments).
>   If there's a proxy server available, try configuring Eclipse to use the proxy via the instructions for Eclipse 3.6, Eclipse 3.5, Eclipse 3.4 or Eclipse 3.3.
>
> If you are still unable to reach the update site, you can try installing the **[Google Plugin for Eclipse from zip files](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html)**.